# Is there a way to skip a particular trigger during apt operations?

Tags: apt, dpkg, initramfs

In particular, I would like to disable the `initramfs-tools` trigger.

I have a script to configure and build the initramfs that I want (which involves multiple kernels), but part of this involves adding and removing various packages, which all trigger a build early.

> Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142) ...

Rather than have to wait for all this pointless activity I just want it to skip the trigger and let me build it manually when ready. Is there any way to get apt/dpkg to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triggers are stored in `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/`. Deleting the relevant script will prevent it from running.

Note that updating the package it belongs to will restore the trigger.